# How to access a 2D array inside an object?

Tags: java, object, casting

I am getting an object as a result of a method call. It is a raster/grid/matrix with rows and columns. But the return type of the method is a object.

On debugging, I can see the 2D array inside. But I am not being able to cast it into anything.

```
Object vPixels = pixelblock3.getPixelDataByRef(0);
Integer[][] wPixels = (Integer[][]) vPixels;
```

I get a ClassCastException at the 2nd line:
`[[B cannot be cast to [[Ljava.lang.Integer;`

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess: try:

```
int[][] wPixels = (int[][]) vPixels;
```

Or

```
byte[][] wPixels = (byte[][]) vPixels;
```

I think that [[B, "B" means primitive bytes.

Comment: you're welcome. If the JVM was more kind, it should have pointed somehow byte instead of a cryptic B :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick to know what is the type of the object:

```
Object vPixels = pixelblock3.getPixelDataByRef(0);
Class cls = vPixels.getClass();
System.out.println("The type of the object is: " + cls.getName());
```

Then you can cast to the appropriate type.

EDIT:
as Luigi pointed out [[B means byte[][] so his answer is the correct one.